# How to prevent device orientation changes on selected screens

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to prevent orientation changes on most screens throughout my app but allow it on some screens

I have tried implementing the following in main():

```
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
  ]);
```

then the following in the other screens initState()

```
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight
  ]);
```

I also tried removing what was in main and puttin it in all screens that required it and then the above but it still always only allows the first of whats been set. Updating for a new set of requirements doesnt seem to be working.

Comment: have you tried to restart your app instead of just hot reload?

Comment: also I am just wild guessing, but try to set orientation in an async method before pushing new route. maybe orientation needs to be set before build method. and since the method returns a future, and you cannot make initState async, try () async {
//await set orientation
//push new route

Comment: I always forget that hot reloading doesn't always work. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There is an open bug in the Flutter repository that describes this behaviour, so it seems like a bug:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13238